# Classic editor, incomplete at that, after WordPress 5.9.3 update. For Posts only it seems

Tags: wordpress, post

I cannot edit my posts after an update to WordPress 5.9.3. They show up in classic editor format with no visual/text editor section. The same is not happening with my Pages though (they appear in block editor). I am using the blocksy theme but the issue does not go away with the Twenty Twenty-Two theme as well. Just to clarify, I want the block editor.

Comment: Di you do any debugging? Please share your own efforts to find the cause. Try https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: this question belongs here, I think: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup.
Deactivate all plugins and test if it works. Change the theme and test if it works.